# Eloquent: Getting sum of values (json property) based on weekday

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to use eloquent to retrieve these results in this order but I haven't had any luck, the **details** column is json type:

Expected Results:

```
Monday: 0
Tuesday: 35
Wednesday: 0
Thursday: 0
Friday: 15
Saturday: 0
Sunday: 0
```

I want to retrieve the day with the highest value basically (word_count), I've tried this:

```
eventLogger::selectRaw('COUNT(*) JSON_EXTRACT(data,"$.word_count"), DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%A") date')->groupBy('date')->get();
```

but I'm always missing something :/

[image: db]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and provide full [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method I used was based on this query I tried on phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(`created_at`) as 'day', SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(`details`,'$.word_count')) AS 'wordCount' FROM event_logger GROUP BY DAYNAME(`created_at`)
```

which translate to eloquent like this:

```
eventLogger::where('userid','=',$user->id)->selectRaw('DAYNAME(`created_at`) as "day", SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(`details`,"$.word_count")) AS "wordCount"')->groupByRaw('DAYNAME(`created_at`)')->orderByRaw("wordCount desc")->get()->toArray();
```

the generated result is like this:

[image]

it displays how many words per weekday for the whole table